# How to remove set of lists from a list of lists

Tags: python, string, list, nested-lists, difference

I have 2 lists of strings

```
List1 = [["Hey there"], ["hi"], ["hello"]]
List2 = [["hi"], ["hello"]]
```

Is there a O(n) way to remove elements of `List2` from `List1`?

Desired output = `[["Hey there"]]`

Comment: List1 - List2 maybe?

Comment: I think you'll have to convert them to sets of tuples to get O(n), using basic language structures.

Comment: FWIW, [here's an *O(n\*m)* method](/a/3428637/4518341)

Comment: @Codingamethyst I don't see a nested loop in the question statement.

Comment: Is there a way to conserve the list of list format and do it?

Comment: Yes, exactly as how it appears in the linked answer.

Comment: @rv.kvetch sorry I meant to say O(n) way only, I'll edit it

Comment: Are the lists all one element? I tried out Kenny's suggestion (actually a variation on it), but I realized that converting to tuple is *O(k)*, which means `set(map(tuple, List2))` is *O(n\*k)*, and I'm basically doing the same thing for `List1`, so in total it's *O(n\*k + m\*j)*. But if all the lists are one-element, *k=1* and *j=1*. In that case I'd also question why they're lists in the first place instead of just the strings, but maybe that's beside the point.

Comment: @wjandrea No, the lists actually contain more than one elements, long sentences rather. I used 1 element lists just as an example.

Comment: Then I don't think it's possible to get *O(n)* since the data itself is *n\*k* size, so anything that consumes all of it must be *O(n\*k)*. Even comparison for example: `List1 == List2` is *O(n\*k + m\*j)*.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with two O(n) steps:

```py
List2_set = set(map(tuple, List2))
List1_filtered = [row for row in List1 if tuple(row) not in List2_set]
```

1. Convert the list of items to exclude to a `set` of `tuples`

   - This conversion is O(n)
   - `set` is required because checking membership for sets is O(1) instead of O(n)
   - `tuple` is required for `set` items instead of `list`, because `tuple` is hashable
2. Check membership for each element of `List1`

   - This check is also O(n)
   - The `set` collection uses a hash table to allow O(1) membership testing

The total then is O(n) + O(n) => O(n), that is, the performance is linear with number of total elements of `List1` + `List2`.